# using OFFSET with an array of columns then SUMPRODUCT

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, offset, sumproduct

i have this formula and it works fine:

`=OFFSET(INDIRECT(CELL("address";INDEX(INDIRECT($F6&"!C:C");MATCH($G$2;INDIRECT($F6&"!C:C");0))));0;14;1;1)`

i give it name of a sheet and a value in a certain column in that sheet and it returns the number in the 14th column in front of that target value. the value in that cell is in fact sum of 12 values beside it (12 values for 12 months of the year).
the hot point: 
`;14;1;1)`

now i want to change the formula so that it returns an array of 12 values so that I can then sumproduct them with another array. actually I want to be able to choose which months to be included in the final sum operation. I changed the above formula to the following:

`SUMPRODUCT(OFFSET(INDIRECT(CELL("address";INDEX(INDIRECT($F6&"!C:C");MATCH($G$2;INDIRECT($F6&"!C:C");0))));0;{2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13};1;1);$E$52:$E$63)`

the changed part:

`SUMPRODUCT( ..... ;{2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13};1;1);$E$52:$E$63)`

a simple change, apparently, but it returns zero.
thanks for help

Comment: I removed the sumproduct part and then copied formula in some other cells, then selected all cells then Ctrl+Shift+Enter but it returns #value error

Comment: by the way, I am in the same workbook. just different sheets

Comment: well, I have some sheets, each for a certain division of the company, all sheets contain the same table structure, a column containing certain activities and in front of it 12 columns for the performance in each month of the year and a column for the total performance. in a report sheet I want to be able to choose 1) the name of the sheet (division) and 2)a specific activity and 3) some specific months of the year, then the formula returns the sum of values for those arguments (an answer to the question: what is total perfomance for that specific division in the specified months)

Comment: a simplified form of my problem:
what is the total perfomance for that specific division in that activity for all months (forget about being able to choose specific months in summation)

Comment: how about showing some sample data for one division (one sheet) so we can see the structure of the data, and demonstrate how you would find the sum based on the activity and month across two sheets for instance. Then we can elaborate it to x number of sheets.

Comment: ok, my data is not in English, I should make a sample. in fact the above formula is for one sheet and one activity. then I change the sheet name and the activity by data validation Dropbox. I think I should correct my problem to this: I have one sheet and one cell (containing an activity) in that sheet and a value in the 14th cell in front of that cell. now how can I return that value to another sheet using a formula that gets the name of the sheet and the activity and the column containing that activity (it should search and find the row containing that activity). this is the core problem

Comment: I changed the formula and the question. as you said it was over-complicated unnecessarily. thanks @terry w

Comment: Are you getting any value of `INDIRECT($F6&"!C:C")`?

Comment: in the formula sheet I have cell $F6 that contains the name of the other sheet, the sheet in which I have the formula search and find in column C, the specified activity (formula gets the activity title from cell $G$2). this may be more descriptive => =OFFSET(INDIRECT(CELL("address";INDEX(INDIRECT([sheetname]&"!C:C");MATCH([acivity];INDIRECT([sheetname]&"!C:C");0))));0;14;1;1)

Comment: Domenic has pointed out the problem for you. I would only suggest you to consider using power query for consolidating data from multiple worksheets instead of using complicated offset+indirect+cell address+match. Alternatively if you can have a master data sheet showing all the data per date per activity per division, then it will be much more easier to use SUMIFS or other simpler formulas to return the desired outcome.

Comment: thanks @Terry W. problem solved. each sheet is filled by its own division and the final consolidated File is not mine, so I prefer it to be as simple as possible. even a simple pivot table I fear to be problematic. if it was mine I would simply have used a macro.

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT(N(OFFSET(INDIRECT(CELL("address",INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&$F6&"'!C:C"),MATCH($G$2,INDIRECT("'"&$F6&"'!C:C"),0)))),0,{2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13})),$E$52:$E$63)

Answer (score 1):

The first argument in SUMPRODUCT returns an array of references.  As such, you'll need to obtain the values from those references by "de-referencing".  One way would be to pass the array of references to the N() function.  So your formula should be as follows...

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(OFFSET(INDIRECT(CELL("address",INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&$F6&"'!C:C"),MATCH($G$2,INDIRECT("'"&$F6&"'!C:C"),0)))),0,{2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13})),$E$52:$E$63)
```

Note that my version of Excel uses the comma as a list separator.  Therefore, adjust the formula accordingly.

Comment: Yep agree. The OP can test this array formula in his system: `SUMPRODUCT(N(OFFSET(INDIRECT(CELL("address";INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&$F6&"'!C:C");MATCH($G$2;INDIRECT("'"&$F6&"'!C:C");0))));0;{2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13}));$E$52:$E$63)`

Comment: amazing! a big smile of success :) @Domenic, Terry W I really thank you. it works finally.